# How to get part of data with Regex

Tags: regex

I have an example which is :

```
[Unit] = 
[Diag] = Nilan zok-98
Alert danger C-00N47

[Unit] = 17B NORWAY 
[Diag] = Mobari-testing-17-AB
Pair num to get 17-9881 to be testing
Class nump

[Unit] = 
[Diag] = BLOC1
```

I want to extract this example in two part like as below :

```
Match 1
Group 1.    [Unit] = 
Group 2.    [Diag] = Nilan zok-98
Alert danger C-00N47

Match 2
Group 1.    [Unit] = 17B NORWAY 
Group 2.    [Diag] = Mobari-testing-17-AB
            Pair num to get 17-9881 to be testing
            Class nump

Match 3
Group 1.    [Unit] = 
Group 2.    [Diag] = BLOC1
```

I was using `(.*\[Unit\].*\n).*(.*\[Diag].*)` to get solution, but Diag section get always first line.

You find my test regex here : https://regex101.com/r/p6nLiK/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
(\[Unit\].*)\n(\[Diag].*(?:\n.+)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qBOqW6/1)

*Details*:

- `(\[Unit\].*)` - Group 1: `[Unit]` and the rest of the line
- `\n` - a line feed  char
- `(\[Diag].*(?:\n.+)*)` - Group 2: `[Diag]`, then the rest of the line and then zero or more non-empty lines.

A variation of the pattern is

```js
(?m)^(\[Unit\].*)\n(\[Diag].*(?:\n\h*\S.*)*)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qBOqW6/2).

Here, `(?m)^` matches any start of line position and `\h*\S.*` makes it match non-blank lines (`\h*` matches zero or more horizontal whitespace and `\S` matches any non-whitespace char). Replace `\h` with `[\p{Zs}\t]` or `[^\S\r\n]` if not supported.